# Sorting and citation of names like "Heather Mac Donald"

Tags: citation

English and citation issue: A person, woman, Heather Mac Donald, the Mac part of the family name, right? Is it being used in sorting or would the person be sorted under Donald?

In sense of [CSL 1.0.1 specification](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#name-particles), is “Mac” a dropping particle, a non-dropping particle or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

*Mac* and *Mc* (and rarely *M'*) are not *dropping particles* and are usually not followed by a space. They may be *something else*. You would expect them to appear with other surnames starting with *M*.

There seem to be three approaches ([Wikipedia has a slightly confused article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_and_Mc_together)):

- Treat them all as spelt *Mac...* so they all appear between *Mabbutt* and *Madden* - this is common with British telephone directories, library sorting and voters lists as it reduces the problems of common mispellings
- Treat them as spelt so those with *Mac...* appear between *Mabbutt* and *Maddox* while those with *Mc...*  between *Mbinda* and *Meacher* - this is easiest to implement for the writer but may be less helpful if there is doubt about spelling
- Treat them as a different section immediately before the *M*s - this is uncommon, and some names should perhaps not be included, such as *Mack* or *Machado*.

Whichever you choose, a further point is not to sort for case.  *Macintyre* and *MacIntyre* should probably appear as if the same name. If you did have a case with *Mac* followed by a space, I would suggest ignoring the space, but this may be a more general collation issue: would you treat *Delacroix* and *de la Croix* as the same name?

You should probably not try to dig deeper.  The Northern Irish politicians [Ken Maginnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Maginnis) and [Martin McGuinness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_McGuinness) had surnames which sounded pretty much the same, but the former would not expect to be included with the *Mac*s.

You may hit a similar issue with some Irish names: the comedian [Dara Ó Briain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dara_%C3%93_Briain) is often spelt *O'Briain* by those without the ability to use diacritics, so these should probably be sorted together, as part of the *O*s.

Answer (score 2):

'Mac' names are filed under M. They are usually written as one word, like Macdonald. Because it's not always easy to remember whether the person spells their name 'Mac...' or 'Mc...', the convention is to list such names in a single sequence as though they all began  with Mac.

I was a professional library cataloguer for many years.

Comment: Note, however, that people using non-Anglicised forms of Gaelic names may consider _Mac_ to be a dropping particle, not part of the surname. So if Heather MacDonald/Macdonald/Mac Donald, assuming she’s Irish and did not marry into the name, chose to use the non-Anglicised form of her name, she may instead be listed as “Domhnaill, Heather Nic” or even (though less likely, I should think) “Dhomhnaill, Heather Nic”.